# Zimbra Admin Page White Screen

Tags: nginx, centos, postfix, zimbra

I'm having an issue where my zimbra admin page (https://zimbraurl:7071/zimbraAdmin) is only showing a white page, F12 is giving me this error.

[image: Exception in launch(): undefined]

[image: Admin_ajj.js.zgz]

I'm running version 8.6.0_GA_1191, I've gone though the typical troubleshooting, no errors in the /var/log/zimbra.log. I have also tried accessing the proxy port directly.

Possibly useful info:

`[zimbra@zimbra ~]$ zmprov gacf | grep Admin
zimbraAdminAccessControlMech: acl
zimbraAdminConsoleCatchAllAddressEnabled: FALSE
zimbraAdminConsoleDNSCheckEnabled: FALSE
zimbraAdminConsoleLDAPAuthEnabled: FALSE
zimbraAdminConsoleSkinEnabled: FALSE
zimbraAdminImapImportNumThreads: 20
zimbraAdminPort: 7071
zimbraAdminProxyPort: 9071
zimbraAdminURL: /zimbraAdmin
zimbraHttpContextPathBasedThreadPoolBalancingFilterRules: /zimbraAdmin:max=5%
zimbraMtaBlockedExtensionWarnAdmin: TRUE
zimbraReverseProxyAdminEnabled: FALSE
zimbraReverseProxyAdminPortAttribute: zimbraAdminPort
zimbraVirusWarnAdmin: TRUE`

Results of /opt/zimbra/log/mailbox.log

`2016-01-20 09:46:31,109 INFO  [qtp509886383-113:https://127.0.0.1:7071/service/admin/soap/GetDomainInfoRequest] [ip=127.0.0.1;ua=ZCS/8.6.0_GA_1191;] soap - GetDomainInfoRequest elapsed=0
2016-01-20 09:46:31,197 INFO  [qtp509886383-112:https://127.0.0.1:7071/service/admin/soap/GetDomainInfoRequest] [ip=127.0.0.1;ua=ZCS/8.6.0_GA_1191;] soap - GetDomainInfoRequest elapsed=0
2016-01-20 09:46:31,354 INFO  [qtp509886383-118:https://127.0.0.1:7071/service/admin/soap/GetDomainInfoRequest] [ip=127.0.0.1;ua=ZCS/8.6.0_GA_1191;] soap - GetDomainInfoRequest elapsed=0
2016-01-20 09:46:31,416 INFO  [qtp509886383-116:https://127.0.0.1:7071/service/admin/soap/GetDomainInfoRequest] [ip=127.0.0.1;ua=ZCS/8.6.0_GA_1191;] soap - GetDomainInfoRequest elapsed=1`

with ?debug=1
[image]

Comment: Maybe clear the browser cache if it is corrupted. Do you have updated your Zimbra server ?

Comment: Tried updating, and also tried 4 different browsers (IE, FF, Chrome, Incog chrome)

Comment: You probably better look in /opt/zimbra/log/mailbox.log

Comment: not much in there, see updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by installing zimbra on another machine (vagrant box) and then copy over `/opt/zimbra/jetty/webapps/zimbraAdmin` (retaining permissions).

`diff` showed a lot of differences, even though I was running the latest patched version it looks like some items were never updated.

I did use the same hostname on the vm as a precaution, it does appear that it would matter.